# Can I use cloud servers as my File Server

Tags: cloud, dropbox, dropbox-api, box

I am currently working on a product development which involves storing files uploaded by the customers at different points.

The client who is funding for the project is looking to minimize the maintenance.
I am thinking to offer him a solution where the files uploaded by the customers will be uploaded to a cloud enterprise account(BOX or DROPBOX) using their API. 
Each customer is awarded with a folder in the cloud service under one enterprise account(Client account) and the code that I am going to write will isolate the permissions only to their registered folders.

 Is this a good solution to avoid maintenance and forget about backing up the file servers regularly?

Answer (score 0):

I've use Box enterprise account, Box can help you this and give you more feature than you want, but Box is too expensive for Enterprise account ($35) or Elite account. And you need to pay for how many times call to Box content API.